# In WCF Ria Services, is it possible to other to connect to my Service? If yes, how can I ban it

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, service, ria

Is it possible for others to connect to my defined services in my Ria application?

If yes, how can we remove this access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very broad question! First of all, you cannot *remove* access, e.g. your URL will still be there and anyone pounding around might accidentally hit it - you can *restrict* access to your service by checking some claims / facts about the caller.

Since a WCF RIA Service is fundamentally a WCF service, you can use any of the WCF mechanisms to secure your service (warning: I'm not familiar with Silverlight, so not all of these might be available / feasible for the limited world of Silverlight clients....):

- require the user to be a valid Windows identity (in Intranet scenarios)
- require a certificate with the caller
- require a specific header in each message
- check the caller's IP

One fairly straightforward solution is being presented here:

[Restricting Access to your WCF Service to a known Silverlight Client](http://10rem.net/blog/2009/07/15/restricting-access-to-your-wcf-service-to-a-known-silverlight-client)

But again - that's just one possible solution out of a vast number of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, It seems that the most effective option is using ASP.Net authentication in my service which was mentioned in your link.